# String is immutable?

Tags: java, string

Just have a problem with this, how do we rewrite the above code so that only a single String object is created?

String is immutable, isnt studentDetails already one single String object

```
public void displayString(Student[] students)
{
   String studentDetails = "";
   for (Student stu : students)
   {
       studentDetails += stu.getFirstName();
       studentDetails += " ";
       studentDetails += stu.getLastName();
       studentDetails += " ";
       studentDetails += stu.getAge();
       studentDetails += "\n";  
   }
   System.out.println("Student Details are: ");
   System.out.println(studentDetails);
}
```

Comment: Use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`

Comment: yes, String objects are immutable

Comment: @DanielM [The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to `[StringBuffer]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Comment: Maybe you could use String.format() inside the loop.

Comment: side bar:  consider allowing `Student` to describe itself by moving `displayString()` to `Student`, or perhaps just override the `Student#toString()` method.

Answer (score 5):

`String` **object** is immutable, while the **variable** `studentDetails` is not.

When you call  `studentDetails += stu.getFirstName()`, you created a new `String` **object** and assign it to **variable** `studentDetails`

Answer (score 3):

Use `StringBuilder`:

```
public void displayString(Student[] students)
{
   StringBuilder studentDetails = new StringBuilder();
   for (Student stu : students)
   {
       studentDetails.append(stu.getFirstName());
       studentDetails.append(' ');
       studentDetails.append(stu.getLastName());
       studentDetails.append(' ');
       studentDetails.append(stu.getAge());
       studentDetails.append('\n');  
   }
   System.out.println("Student Details are: ");
   System.out.println(studentDetails.toString());
}
```

> String is immutable, isnt studentDetails already one single String object

No, since each time you append two `String`s with `+=`, a new `String` is created.

Comment: The principle is sound but that will create 4 `String` objects, not one. (Edit: not sure if OP's specification to create a single `String` object might be a bit of XY though).

Comment: @Mena yes, I noticed that and replaced the single character Strings with chars. Still, there would be a second `String` ("Student Details are: "). I think the only way to avoid that is to append the characters of that constant String one at a time to the start of the StringBuilder, but that would be ridiculous.

Comment: @Mena I see only one. How do you count?

Comment: @kumesana there are two in the latest version of the answer (see Eran's comment above). In the previous version the char literals were `String` literals. So you had one for the whitespace, one for the newline, one for the "Student details..." and one for the `toString` invocation.

Comment: Those are literals, not really created when running this code... I suppose it's a matter of semantics.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable - Use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` (thread-safe) instead

```
public void displayString(Student[] students)
{
   StringBuilder studentDetails = new StringBuilder();
   for (Student stu : students)
   {
       studentDetails.append(stu.getFirstName());
       studentDetails.append(" ");
       studentDetails.append(stu.getLastName());
       studentDetails.append(" ");
       studentDetails.append(stu.getAge());
       studentDetails.append("\n");  
   }
   System.out.println("Student Details are: ");
   System.out.println(studentDetails.toString());
}
```

Comment: synchronization is useless here. Prefer StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `String` object is immutable, that is why one need to work with `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`. Below are steps shown to work with `StringBuilder`

- Create variable of type `StringBuilder`
- Use `append()` method to concnat `String`
- Call `toString()` to convert it into `String`

Answer (score 0):

yes, strings are immutable, just use a StringBuilder, or a stringBuffer if thread safe is required....

```
   StringBuilder studentDetails = "";
   for (Student stu : students)
   {
       studentDetails.append(stu.getFirstName());
       studentDetails.append(" ");
       studentDetails.append(stu.getLastName());
       studentDetails.append(" ");
       studentDetails.append(stu.getAge());
       studentDetails.append("\n");  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , The string object in java is immutable.
The any change in the string will create the new string object.
Whereas, the stringBuilder and StringBuffer are mutable